# GCP composer set up in VS code

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am new to GCP, I have to set up GCP composer through VS code. Is there any way to do same. I could not find much info on same in google.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean? To set up a Cloud Composer, you can do it manually via the console. then, if you want to deploy it via code, i suggest you to use Terraform which allows you to provision you cloud infrastructure via Infrastructure as Code (IaC). You can use it in VSCode, IntelliJ or any IDE you want to use.

Comment: Hi Dev Yns, Thank you for your comment. As I am working in office set up so not sure I can use terraform or not. I was just checking if I can do the dev for script through VS code, which will be directly updated in composer script location. So we don't have to upload the scripts and run manually.

Comment: VS Code is just an IDE where you can write some code to do whatever you want. Your task is to set up a Google Cloud Composer, to do so i suggest you to use Terraform code. Or if you want you want use the Google Cloud Client Library for Python or any other language.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your `Cloud Composer` instance and manage it with :

- `Terraform` (HCL) : https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/composer_environment
- `GCloud sdk` (shell) :
  https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/create-environments?hl=en#gcloud
- `API` with your preferred client or language (Python, Java, Node, Postman...) :
  https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/create-environments?hl=en#api

`VS code` proposes supports for all of these languages.
Depending on what you choose, you can manage the code with `VS Code`.

The most important for you is to chose the most appropriate language to manage your cluster.

`Terraform` is more natural to manage infrastructure and uses a state management to control the changes. It proposes a `DSL` with existing `resource` to create, update or delete a `Cloud Composer` cluster...

If you use `API` or `GCloud sdk`, you have to develop your code logic or configuration to manage your `Cloud Composer` cluster.